# Can't connect Usb modem on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, usb, lubuntu, 16.04, usb-modem

My usb modem is detecting in network manager, however on clicking connect button, it keeps on going for few minutes and disconnects thereafter.

Please see output of various queries below-

**lsusb:**

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co.,Ltd. Modem/Networkcard

**wvdial:**

WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Device or resource busy
Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Device or resource busy
Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: Device or resource busy

I also tried to install drivers as suggested in many forums, and modeswitch but with no joy. Please see output of

**sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1506 -M "55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"**

Look for default devices ...
   product ID matched
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 003 on bus 002
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
Use endpoints 0x02 (out) and 0x82 (in)
Error: can't use storage command in MessageContent with interface 0;
       interface class is 255, expected 8. Abort

Please suggest what I might be missing here.

Regards,

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried a lot but no result yet. Please let me know if anyone have a suggestion. Regards